# Matrix inverse issue with numpy.linalg.inv()

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, matrix-inverse

I have an array AP3T which looks like this
[image: Matrix A]

I need to get the inverse of this matrix. I am using np.linalg.inv().
But when I pass this array to the function i get this error[image]

What is the problem? While creating the array AP3T I used dtype = np.float64

Comment: Tell us about the array, specifically `dtype` and `shape`.

Comment: as i mentioned the dtype is np.float64 and shape is n*n. I want to build a data matrix for normal equation.

Comment: as long as the matrix is 6*6 everything works just fine but afterwards eg 7*7 the error occurs. to mention that the values in the matrix increases polynomialy with the shape

Comment: Since you can't (or at least haven't) provide us with a reproducible example, we can't do much to help.  Especially if one size works, but another size (is it just size, or is something else going on?) doesn't.  The error (is that the complete text?) suggests there's something wrong with the `dtype` - `signature` and `casting`.

Comment: I can make a random float (7,7) array and calculate the `inv` without problem.  So if you are having problems, there is something wrong/different about your array.  For example if the `dtype` was string I get your error message.  Or object dtype.

Comment: Thanks the problem solved. Actually i was creating the array by pushing value into it. So after your comment i tried the same thing just by typecasting the value to float, and it worked perfectly. but still it is unclear for me why it was working for small values but not for big float values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pushing value into it".  I suspect it changed the array's dtype, so it was no longer `float64`.

Comment: I was appending the values into array(). And as you when appending the value was appended into array it might changed the array type.